# how to draw guide lines on a gnuplot generated cdf?

Tags: r, statistics, gnuplot, data-visualization, cdf

At work have a set of floating point values that I sort and compute a CDF for and plot within gnuplot.  I'd like to draw a line showing where the 80% and 90% thresholds of the CDF are, i.e. a line coming in from the left @ the 0.8 y tic mark, touching the graph and then dropping down to whatever that value might be.  This is to help guide the viewers eye.

The data is generated automatically and I make multiple plots so I don't want to have to hand craft these lines each time.

It's trivial to draw a horizontal arrow going completely across the plot at the 0.8 and 0.9 y-value points, but I don't understand how to determine where the vertical line should be drawn.
Here is a q/a wrt drawing arrows: [Gnuplot: Vertical lines at specific positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499998/gnuplot-vertical-lines-at-specific-positions/8562193#8562193), but the positions are known a priori.

Here is some sample data (my work machine is not internet accessible so sharing is hard)

```
  X                Y
 5.0   |         0.143
 8.0   |         0.288
16.0   |         0.429
25.0   |         0.714
39.0   |         0.857
47.0   |         1.000
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my take (using percentile ranks), which only assumes a univariate series of measurement is available (your column headed `X`). You may want to tweak it a little to work with your pre-computed cumulative frequencies, but that's not really difficult.

```
# generate some artificial data
reset
set sample 200
set table 'rnd.dat'
plot invnorm(rand(0))
unset table

# display the CDF
unset key
set yrange [0:1]
perc80=system("cat rnd.dat | sed '1,4d' | awk '{print $2}' | sort -n | \
          awk 'BEGIN{i=0} {s[i]=$1; i++;} END{print s[int(NR*0.8-0.5)]}'")
set arrow from perc80,0 to perc80,0.8 nohead lt 2 lw 2
set arrow from graph(0,0),0.8 to perc80,0.8 nohead lt 2 lw 2
plot 'rnd.dat' using 2:(1./200.) smooth cumulative
```

This yields the following output:

[image]

You can add as many percentile values as you want, of course; you just have to define a new variable, e.g. `perc90`, as well as ask for two other `arrow` commands, and replace every occurrence of `0.8` (ah... the joy of magic numbers!) by the desired one (in this case, 0.9).

Some explanations about the above code:

1. I generated an artificial dataset which was saved on disk.
2. The 80th percentile is compute using awk, but before that we need to

   1. remove the header generated by `table` (first four lines); (we could ask awk to start at the 5th lines, but let's go with that.)
   2. keep only the second column;
   3. sort the entries.
3. The awk command to compute the 80th percentile requires truncation, which is done as suggested [here](http://braindump.mrzesty.net/63.html). (In R, I would simply use a function like `trunc(rank(x))/length(x)` to get the percentile ranks.)

If you want to give R a shot, you can safely replace that long series of sed/awk commands with a call to R like

```
Rscript -e 'x=read.table("~/rnd.dat")[,2]; sort(x)[trunc(length(x)*.8)]'
```

assuming `rnd.dat` is in your home directory.

---

**Sidenote:** And if you can live without gnuplot, here are some R commands to do that kind of graphics (even not using the `quantile` function):

```
x <- rnorm(200)
xs <- sort(x)
xf <- (1:length(xs))/length(xs)
plot(xs, xf, xlab="X", ylab="Cumulative frequency")
## quick outline of the 80th percentile rank
perc80 <- xs[trunc(length(x)*.8)]
abline(h=.8, v=perc80) 
## alternative solution
plot(ecdf(x))
segments(par("usr")[1], .8, perc80, .8)
segments(perc80, par("usr")[3], perc80, .8)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` to calculate the line at a given value.

#### Example

If you have a data file `Data.csv` like so:

```
0     1
1     4
2     9
3    16
4    25
5    36
6    49
7    64
8    81
9   100
```

you can plot it with

```
plot "Data.csv" u 1:2 w l
```

Now if you want to draw a line at 90% of the maximal value of the second column (in this case 90) run an awk script. Its purpose is to identify the minimum and maximum x-value and the 90% value of the maximal y-value. It could look something like this:

```
awk '
{
if(x_min == "") {x_min = x_max = $1; y_max = $2}; 
if($1 > x_max) {x_max = $1}; 
if($1 < x_min) {x_min = $1}; 
if(y_max < $2) {y_max = $2}} 
END {
print x_min, y_max * 0.9; 
print x_max, y_max * 0.9
}' Data.csv
```

Basically what it does is the following:

1. Check if `x_min` exists and if it does not set `x_min`, `x_max` and `y_max` to the first or second column of `Data.csv`.
2. Check if the current first column is larger than the current `x_min`, if that is the case, set `x_min` to the value of the current first column.
3. Do the equivalent for `x_max` and `y_max` (Note: we only need the maximum of the second column and not the minimum)
4. After we looped through our data file print the result like so:

   ```
   x_min y_max * 0.9
   x_max y_max * 0.9
   ```

In order to make this work in gnuplot we append our script from above like so:

```
plot "Data.csv" u 1:2 w l, \
     "< awk '{if(x_min == \"\") {x_min = x_max = $1; y_max = $2}; if($1 > x_max) {x_max = $1}; if($1 < x_min) {x_min = $1}; if(y_max < $2) {y_max = $2}} END {print x_min, y_max * 0.9; print x_max, y_max * 0.9}' Data.csv" u 1:2 w l
```

Note the `\"` in the gnuplot script. The `"` need to be escaped for gnuplot not to stumble over them...

After all you should end up with a plot like this:

[image]

The green line marks the 90% value of the maximal y-value.

Comment: Starting with Gnuplot 4.3, cumulative distribution functions are available using `smooth cumulative` (see also [*Gnuplot in Action*](http://www.manning.com/janert/), pp. 259-260). So, the simplest solution would be to do something like: plot "random-points" u 1:(1./300.) smooth cumulative title "Random points" ␍ replot 0.8 lt 2 title "80th percentile" ␍ replot 0.9 lt 2 title "90th percentile". However, I don't see how your code might help in drawing the corresponding vertical lines because the OP is more or less after something that looks like http://i.imgur.com/KwSFh.png.