# Gnuplot plot 2D matrix with image, want to draw borders for each cell

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I want to plot a 18x18 matrix with gnuplot. Here is my codes:

```
set size ratio 1
set palette gray negative
set xrange[-0.5:17.5]
set yrange[-0.5:17.5]
set cbrange[-0.2:0.8]
set xtics 0,1,17
set ytics 0,1,17
set xtics offset -0.5,0
set title "Resolusition Matrix for E"
plot "Mat" matrix w image noti
```

Then I got a fig like this:

[image]

Now I would like to add borders to each cell, which will look like this:

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For your case you can set one minor tic, which then lies on the border between two pixels, and draw a grid on them:

```
set size ratio 1
set palette gray negative
set autoscale xfix
set autoscale yfix
set xtics 1
set ytics 1
set title "Resolution Matrix for E"

set tics scale 0,0.001
set mxtics 2
set mytics 2
set grid front mxtics mytics lw 1.5 lt -1 lc rgb 'white'
plot "Mat" matrix w image noti
```

Note, that `set grid front` also brings the tics to the front. To avoid that you can scale the tics to `0`. For the minor tics you must use a very small number, `0` would omit the grid lines on the minor tics.

The result with 4.6.3 is:

[image]

EDIT: In order to control the grid lines and tic labels independently, you can use the unused `x2` and `y2` to draw the grid (inspired by an answer to [How do I draw a vertical line in gnuplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19152883/2604213)):

```
set size ratio 1
set palette gray negative
# grid lines
set x2tics 1 format '' scale 0,0.001
set y2tics 1 format '' scale 0,0.001
set mx2tics 2
set my2tics 2

# labeling
set xtics 5 out nomirror
set ytics 5 out nomirror

set grid front mx2tics my2tics lw 1.5 lt -1 lc rgb 'white'

set xrange[-0.5:39.5]
set yrange[-0.5:39.5]
set x2range[-0.5:39.5]
set y2range[-0.5:39.5]

plot "Mat" matrix w image notitle
```

With `gnuplot` version 4.6, this requires setting explicit ranges, so that the `x` and `x2` (unused!) are equal. The information might be extracted with `stats` from the data file.

Using version 5 allows you to use `set link`. Instead of all the `set *range` stuff. You could use:

```
set autoscale fix
set link x
set link y
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Now here's another issue. I have a larger matrix 80x80, the label looks very busy. I want avoid the numbers beneath the tics but keep the tics themselves to show the grid.

Comment: @Kai I found, what I would consider the optimal solution, to control the labels and the grid lines independent of each other.