# Gnuplot Vertical Dashed Line

Tags: linux, gnuplot

I would like to add a gray dashed vertical line on my graph with GNUPLOT.

My terminal is;

```
set terminal postscript portrait enhanced color dashed lw 1 "DejaVuSans" 12 size 6,6
set output "pic.ps"
set xrange [30:110]
plot 'smth.txt' w lines ls 7 t ""
```

I have looked into several ideas around but there seems to no explanation about how to get a dashed gray line vertically at let's say x = 40 (the line gonna be parallel to y-axis)

[image: The image I have is like this;]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I draw a vertical line in gnuplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457046/how-do-i-draw-a-vertical-line-in-gnuplot)

Comment: this is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35613933/7295599 besides other confusing ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to use the `set arrow` command and remove the head to make it a line:

```
set arrow from 40,0 to 40,100 nohead lc rgb 'red' dt 2
```

Your graph does not specify any y value, so adjust it to a "larger than needed" value.

For dash type (`dt`), [checkout p.42 of manual](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_5.2/Gnuplot_5.2.pdf). It is terminal-dependent (I didn't tried with postscript), but you can adjust as needed.